# Dart Error: "Expected an identifier, but got ')'" in Flutter Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax-error

While developing a Flutter app, I encountered a compilation error stating "Expected an identifier, but got ')'." This error points to my `StartPomodoro` widget, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. Below are the relevant Dart code snippets showcasing the implementation of the `StartPomodoro` class and its usage, along with the exact error message from the debug console.

**Error Message:**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode... 
lib\main.dart:1 Error: Expected an identifier, but got ')'. 
lib/apilar_codigo/stacked_all.dart:20 Try inserting an identifier before ')'. 
StartPomodoro(end: ),
Failed to compile application. Exited (sigterm)
```

**Code Snippet:**

**startpomodoro.dart**

```
 class StartPomodoro extends StatefulWidget {
       StartPomodoro({super.key, required this.end});
    
      final DateTime end;
    
      @override
      State<StartPomodoro> createState() => _StartPomodoroState();
    }
    
    class _StartPomodoroState extends State<StartPomodoro>
        with TickerProviderStateMixin {
      final now = DateTime.now();
    
      List<bool> isSelected = [true, false];
      late Timer timer;
      late AnimationController controller;
```

**StackPages.dart**

```
class StackPages extends StatelessWidget {
  const StackPages({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
    
      children:   [
         StartPomodoro(end: ),    
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Attempted Solutions:**

- I've made sure that the `end` parameter in the `StartPomodoro` widget is properly provided with a `DateTime` object.
- I've checked for missing identifiers and syntax issues around the area indicated by the error message but couldn't find any obvious mistakes.

**Questions:**

1. What specifically causes this error in the context of my `StartPomodoro` widget's implementation or usage?
2. Are there any best practices I should follow when declaring widgets with required parameters in Flutter to avoid such errors?

I appreciate any help or insights you can offer on resolving this compilation issue.

Comment: Share stacked_all.dart

Comment: the constructor needs an argument of DateTime StartPomodoro({super.key, required this.end}); you can try  StartPomodoro(end: DateTime.now())), it should work but you have to adjust the date with your app needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Parameter `end` is of type `DateTime`.
- To get over this error provide value of type `DateTime` in `end` parameter.

  Try following code:

  ```
  StartPomodoro(end: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1)))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

: Error: Expected an identifier, but got ':'.
../…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:147
Try inserting an identifier before ':'.
:rethrow;
^
: Error: Expected ';' after this.
../…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:146
});
^
: Error: Unexpected token ':'.
../…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:147
:rethrow;

getting this error in my code i haven't created anything yet but still showing this error it has to show the basic hello world counter interface,but its not showing that also ,what's the problem I am getting I don't know  previously I creating  a project but while I was in the middle of that project the same issue had occure after that project everytime if I creating a new project also it showing the same error.

Comment: This does not seem an answer to the question asked, but rather a problem you experience.